# WebView not showing content properly iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webview, uiwebview

I am having issue with WebView on Xcode. I have uses framework7 for frontend since it is working amazing. When I open link in safari on iphone everything is scaled good, when I insert it in WebView and launch it on iphone the bottom of the app is cutoff, I can scroll to it (if I enable scroll), but it is not what I want to do, I want it to scale on the screen, like it does on browser.
This is it, left is safari, right webview 
http://postimg.org/image/xwkuo85e5/
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

try again with adding options for webview

```
self.yourWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.yourWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```